# C++ Class object as argument of function

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have two functions in two different files

in file A.cpp

`void func(int x, A a){...}`

in file B.cpp

`void func(int x, B b){...}`

These two functions do pretty much the same thing, so I would like to merge them, i.e., create a function in file C.cpp who will look like this

`void func(int x, AorB c){...}`. I don't want my function to look like
`void func(int x, A a, B b){...}`

I'd like to create a class `AorB` such that my `c` object is either of type `A` or `B` depending on which object I pass to the function.

Comment: It sounds like you want [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)

Comment: Just to be clear, is the parameter A in the first function a instance of a class defined by the file A.cpp? Or is the A.cpp completely unrelated to the parameter A in func(int x, A a)? In any case, what you are describing sounds like polymorphism. You want an abstract base class and A and B are derived from that class. A function can then accept a pointer to the abstract base class type, which means it can accept either and A or a B pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templates could help here, if the processing is the same:

```
template <class X>
void func(int x, X b) {
    ...
}
```

But beware, templates have to be resolved at compile time, so they have to reside in header files and not in separate compilation units.